# Is safe to thaw frozen salmon or tuna to 3-4°C and keep it for 14-15 hours before cooking?

Tags: food-safety, salmon

I wish to add salmon or tuna (packaged pieces, not whole fish) as regular part of my diet, and I am currently experimenting with finding a way to cook them that works best for me from a point of time management.

One thing I am unsure about is how safe it is to thaw the frozen pieces during the night (over a span of 12-15 hours or so) while keeping it at 3-4°C in my fridge.

My understanding is that whatever pathogens are in the fish when I buy it frozen will of course still be there, but won't really start growing significantly at temperatures up to 4°C over half a day, give or take.

Is that assumption correct? Is there any other reason not to thaw it in advance?

Is a "smell test" (i.e., checking that it smells neutral just before cooking) enough to rule out any problems, or can it be more complicated?

The fish will be heated to 55°C internal temperature during cooking in any case.

Comment: Hi, we have long stopped answering this kind of question - they are endless, and all of them only require the absolutely literal application of the rules. We have written up the basics of food safety in the tag info, I suggest that you go through them and through the questions linked there. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info.

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to that ressource - all my questions were answered. @rumtscho The side panel doesn't say anything about food safety (only "Please note that requests for recipes are considered off topic, and will be closed."). I think it would be cool to expand that with the info/link you gave me as well. Even though I am on SE for many years, I wasn't aware that there can be info pages behind tags (aside from the little blurb you get on mouseover), and certainly wasn't aware that there is a gem like this one hidden here!